# Vectorize large NumPy multiplication

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, multiplication

I am interested in calculating a large NumPy array. I have a large array `A` which contains a bunch of numbers. I want to calculate the sum of different combinations of these numbers. The structure of the data is as follows:

```
A = np.random.uniform(0,1, (3743, 1388, 3))
Combinations = np.random.randint(0,3, (306,3))
Final_Product = np.array([  np.sum( A*cb, axis=2)  for cb in Combinations])
```

My question is if there is a more elegant and memory efficient way to calculate this? I find it frustrating to work with `np.dot()` when a 3-D array is involved.

If it helps, the shape of `Final_Product` ideally should be (3743, 306, 1388). Currently `Final_Product` is of the shape (306, 3743, 1388), so I can just reshape to get there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`np.dot()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) won't give give you the desired output , unless you involve extra step(s) that would probably include `reshaping`. Here's one `vectorized` approach using [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) to do it one shot without any extra memory overhead -

```
Final_Product = np.einsum('ijk,lk->lij',A,Combinations)
```

For *completeness*, here's with `np.dot` and `reshaping` as discussed earlier -

```
M,N,R = A.shape
Final_Product = A.reshape(-1,R).dot(Combinations.T).T.reshape(-1,M,N)
```

Runtime tests and verify output -

```
In [138]: # Inputs ( smaller version of those listed in question )
     ...: A = np.random.uniform(0,1, (374, 138, 3))
     ...: Combinations = np.random.randint(0,3, (30,3))
     ...: 

In [139]: %timeit np.array([  np.sum( A*cb, axis=2)  for cb in Combinations])
1 loops, best of 3: 324 ms per loop

In [140]: %timeit np.einsum('ijk,lk->lij',A,Combinations)
10 loops, best of 3: 32 ms per loop

In [141]: M,N,R = A.shape

In [142]: %timeit A.reshape(-1,R).dot(Combinations.T).T.reshape(-1,M,N)
100 loops, best of 3: 15.6 ms per loop

In [143]: Final_Product =np.array([np.sum( A*cb, axis=2)  for cb in Combinations])
     ...: Final_Product2 = np.einsum('ijk,lk->lij',A,Combinations)
     ...: M,N,R = A.shape
     ...: Final_Product3 = A.reshape(-1,R).dot(Combinations.T).T.reshape(-1,M,N)
     ...: 

In [144]: print np.allclose(Final_Product,Final_Product2)
True

In [145]: print np.allclose(Final_Product,Final_Product3)
True
```

Comment: Thanks! I also found @ajcr 's answer to be very helpful. Using tensor I halved the time used in `np.einsum`

Comment: @Julien I like ajcr's solution too! I think it's a succinct version of what `dot` does here.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `dot` you could use [`tensordot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html). Your current method is equivalent to:

```
np.tensordot(A, Combinations, [2, 1]).transpose(2, 0, 1)
```

Note the `transpose` at the end to put the axes in the correct order.

Like `dot`, the `tensordot` function can call down to the fast BLAS/LAPACK libraries (if you have them installed) and so should be perform well for large arrays.

Comment: Short and simple, I like it!

Comment: @Divakar: thanks! I still prefer `einsum` though :-)

Comment: Me too!! I had this feeling when `einsum` puts out a 3D array, it's not as efficient as reducing into a `2D` array or best a `scalar`.